# Does the used capacity of RAM have an effect on speed of data retrieval from it?

Tags: hardware, ram

Does the used capacity of RAM have an effect on speed of data retrieval from it?

Basically the more RAM is used, the slower the data retrieval? Or does it not matter since the L caches are made to be so fast?

Comment: Neither RAM nor hard drives become slower at reading based on how much they store (with SSDs, performance can degrade on writing but not on reading). Where did you get the idea that hard drives did?

Comment: RAM (and standard hard disk) does not know whether it's "used" or not.  A valid data byte and a "garbage" byte look identical to the RAM.

Comment: @DarkFalcon - that's not really true.  Fragmentation tends to slow storage media where access involves physical movement of heads.  But most systems do not suffer from this for RAM, as there is little "inertia" of access abd their memory management unit can map distributed physical pages into a contiguous logical chunk.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: But that is fragmentation, which can also affect storage with plenty of free space. And it doesn't slow the storage media at all. It simply requires more accesses to it. The media still operates at the exact same speed.

Comment: Caching, however, could mean that having little storage in currently *active* use leads to higher speed, since less data has to share the presumably limited cache.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that Windows make a reference note so it doesn't affect the reading speed. But I'm not sure how RAM retrieves data?

Comment: @DarkFalcon.  No.  Fragmentation does not occur on media with plenty of free space at the time of writing, unless the allocation algorithm is poor.  And fragmentation notably slows access, as there is a seek time penalty when the heads physically move between fragments.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - "Fragmentation" is not a property of the drive but rather a property of the operating system and how it manages the drive.  Fragmentation may slow the *management* of the drive, but does not slow actual physical data transfer operations.

Comment: That's not what matters.  The question asked about "the speed of data retrieval" - on a geometrically addressed drive, if you have to keep jumping around to access your data, that is in fact slower than if you can do one contiguous access. The poster made a quite valid point, which you are quite invalidly dismissing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as used or unused ram.  All the bits of ram always have a value.  From a RAM perspective there is clearly no difference in performance randomly accessing one address or another.

Unless you are talking about an embedded system with no operating system or maybe only one task running and dominating memory, there is not much you can do with the cache, predicting, tuning for performance, etc.  your so called unused memory isnt going to hurt any more than accessing used memory or linearly walking through memory, the most pain you can have with caches is striping, powers of two that defeat the cache and only allow a fraction of it to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

"Why do you care?" and "What would you do about it?" are reasonable responses to this question... But let me see if I can answer it anyway.

As the comments suggest, in general the access speed of memory does not depend on how "full" it is.

As with hard drives, the only potential problem is fragmentation, because the memory itself has no idea whether it is in use or free. But virtual memory presents even fragmented memory as contiguous, thus hiding the fragmentation from the CPU and (presumably) from any pre-fetching machinery the CPU might use. So in general, memory fragmentation is irrelevant to performance.

That said, there is a mechanism on at least one O/S -- i.e. Linux -- that could allow fragmented physical memory to harm performance. "Transparent hugepages" is an optimization for large memory workloads that uses large (or, um, huge) pages to reduce the number of TLB entries and therefore the number of TLB misses. This optimization can improve performance by 2% or more on such workloads. But the transparent hugepages machinery can only kick in when large (2 megabyte) aligned and contiguous physical RAM is free for allocation; badly fragmented physical RAM will thus inhibit it.

Comment: You seem to be overlooking a far simpler concern: the limited capacity of cache.  The more "active" data stored, the greater the likelihood of a cache miss slowing operations.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: That depends entirely on the locality of your access patterns, which is not necessarily correlated with the amount of memory in use. Unless you are talking about a working set that fits largely or entirely in cache, that is, which I concede I was overlooking. I am used to dealing with memory in the gigabytes and files in the hundreds of gigabytes, so memory footprints on the scale of caches do not naturally occur to me :-)